# Laravel 5.3 Custom Path for Post-authentication Redirect

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two types of users: "vendors" and "clients". And I'm currently using `Laravel's built-in Auth Controllers` (from the `make:auth` command) to do my client user authentication.

And since I have two kinds of users, I have changed the `$redirectTo` property on the `LoginController`, `RegisterController`, and `ResetPasswordController` to `/client/home`.

Here is proof:

[RegisterController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs28l.png)
[LoginController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs64y.png)

Now, it redirects to `/client/home` every time I successfully do registration, login, and password reset.

But the problem is when I'm in `mysite.com/client/home` already, whenever I would try to go to `mysite.com/register` or `mysite.com/login` via the address bar, it would redirect to `mysite.com/home` instead of `mysite.com/client/home`...

How can I make it redirect to `mysite.com/client/home` whenever an authenticated user tries to go to `/login` or `/register`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option is to create separate controllers for both of your login areas. It will be easier to manage later on, and you can customise the behaviour a bit better.

The default folder structure looks like this:

```
app
|__Http
   |__Controllers
      |__Auth
         |__ForgotPasswordController.php
         |__LoginController.php
         |__RegisterController.php
         |__ResetPasswordController.php
```

You could create an additional folder for your client controllers, like so:

```
app
|__Http
   |__Controllers
      |__Auth
      |  |__ForgotPasswordController.php
      |  |__LoginController.php
      |  |__RegisterController.php
      |  |__ResetPasswordController.php
      |__Client
         |__Auth
            |__ForgotPasswordController.php
            |__LoginController.php
            |__RegisterController.php
            |__ResetPasswordController.php
```

This way you can customise the `$redirectTo` properties of each controllers individually.

As an alternative solution, you could overwrite the `redirectPath` of the RedirectsUsers trait, by creating a `redirectPath` method in your respective controllers, and return the URL you'd like:

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (\Request::is('client/*'))
    {
        return url('client/home');
    }

    return url('home');
}
```

The advantage of this second solution is that you can return controller actions and named routes as well. I personally don't like routing to URLs, as if I ever decide to change them, then I'll have to change them everywhere. Using controller actions seems like a better idea, but you could run into the same problem if you refactor your code later on. I prefer using named routes, as I can give them a sensible name, and never change them again, yet still keep all my redirects in a working order.

Comment: So if I made a Clients folder for the specific-to-clients auth controllers and directed my routes to them, I'd just have to set their individual redirectTo property to 'client/home' and I'd get my desired output already?

Comment: Yes, you would.