# Redirect is not working in LogSuccessfulLogin handle in Laravel Auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.3, laravel-authorization, laravel-events

I am using `Laravel 5.3` in which using `Auth`for user controller.
So basically i create a `Listener` for `Auth` Event

```
'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
    'App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogin',
],
```

and in `LogSuccessfulLogin` `handle()` function redirecting user on basic of `role`. but my redirecting function is not working. Its render the default page '\home' route.

I am sharing My Files :-

EventServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\SomeEvent' => [
            'App\Listeners\EventListener',
        ],
        'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
            'App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogin',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        //
    }
}
```

Route/web.php

```
<?php
//Auth::routes();
Route::get('logout', function(){
    Auth::logout(); // logout user
    return Redirect::to('/');
});
#Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('homepage');
Route::get('/', function () {return view('welcome');});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'checkrole:Admin'],'namespace' => 'Admin','prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/123','DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
    #Route::get('/','DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');

    Route::get('user/profile', function () {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });
});
```

and here is LogSuccessfulLogin.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
class LogSuccessfulLogin
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  Login  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Login $event)
    {

        $user=Auth::User()->role->role_name;
        if($user=="Admin"){
            return Redirect::route('dashboard');
            #return redirect()->route('login');
        }
        elseif($user == "Employer" ){
            dd("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the default logincontroller of Auth

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if i am doing some wrong.
Actually i also tried in `LogSuccessfulLogin` Listener for redirect the page with `return redirect()->route('login');` but its also not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532803/laravel-5-3-custom-path-for-post-authentication-redirect

Comment: anyway you are doing wrong to return redirect object from Event - app does not listen what event handler returns. You can redirect user only returning Redirect::to() from controller, middleware or Route callback

Comment: Actually i am `symfony` developer and recently i am working on Laravel. In sf we can redirect from LoginsuccessHanlder.

Comment: @Silwerclaw can you suggest me better way to got this approach.

Answer (score 2):

As one of possible solutions I would provide a response middleware that will be attached to login route. After getting response you should check if user is logged and if yes - apply your custom redirection login. In that case you will overwrite default Laravel 5.3 logic of redirection. Smth like this:

```
class PostLoginMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        // here you've already have response and it's usually redirect
        $response = $next($request);

        // if user logged in
        if (\Auth::id()) {
             $customRedirectResponse = // ...apply your custom logic

             return $customRedirectResponse;
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

You should define this middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php in

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'custom-redirect' => \YourNamespace\PostLoginMiddleware::class
];
```

And then apply it on login route

```
/* Authentication Routes */
$this->get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
$this->post('login', ['middleware' => 'custom-redirect', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@login']);
$this->get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have some confusion related to `customRedirectResponse `, So can you explain a little bit more. Like here i need to put the redirect routing url or any other thing .

Comment: you have to insert there what you wrote in Event handler.

Comment: Okay I got it. So basically the whole code of my Event Listener will be there.

Comment: When i am logged out. its give me error `Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers' not found`