# Creating custom redirect logic in Laravel 5.3; can't log users in

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to do custom redirect logic upon logging in to my site. So I wrote this code

```
public function login()
{
    $user = //what do I put here?
    $this->guard()->login($user);
    $id = Auth::id();
    //dd($id);
    $rfid = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->value('reference_id');
    if ($rfid == null){
        dd($id);
        return redirect()->action('RedirectController@client');
    }
    else {
        //dd($rfid);
        return redirect()->action('RedirectController@employee');
    }
}
```

However my problem is that all it does is redirect. Which makes sense. The code I have there only manages the redirect, there is nothing there to actually log anyone in. So I did some researching and found

```
 $this->guard()->login($user);
```

As a way to log the user in. However I don't know what to define the variable $user as. I know this should work because I use it in a different place on my site, but it the $user variable that I use there wouldn't work here. So under the scenario of simply login in the user, what do put there in order to authorize the user as in our database, and then log them in?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Laravel 5.3 `AuthenticatesUsers` traits , you will understand how login works behind the scene.

you need to change your `login` method to use `attempt` instead of `login` as follows to work it accordingly.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
 $user = //what do I put here?
 $this->guard()->attempt($this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember'));
 $id = Auth::id();
 //dd($id);
 $rfid = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->value('reference_id');
 if ($rfid == null){
     dd($id);
     return redirect()->action('RedirectController@client');
 }
 else {
     //dd($rfid);
     return redirect()->action('RedirectController@employee');
 }}
```

I recommend you to use it as I mentioned. If you still want to get `$user` value you can try out

```
$user = $this->guard()->user();
```

Though I haven't used it like that.

Comment: I'll give that a go. I also found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532803/laravel-5-3-custom-path-for-post-authentication-redirect and changed my code to look like below. https://gyazo.com/e6446cc3fc81a0fbe54cdda82c9461f3

Would you suggest that I keep what I have right now (that works as far as I know) or use your method above?

Comment: I personally don't like to divert too much from core framework methods until it's utter necessity. Overriding the methods to include your customisation is good way to go.

Comment: Go with what you have above then?

Comment: you can use your current implementation if you only want to login user and don't need other boilerplate methods like throttle, logout etc.